# Symfony folder structure

Tags: symfony, sonata

After installed some bundles like Sonata I am confused about folder structure. First I have created a folder in src called appBundle with folders like entity,controller,form etc. Now that I installed sonata userbundle and extended it with easyExtends it created another folder in src called Application/Sonata/userbundle and inside folders like entity,controller etc. My question is, is it possible to have everything in my appBundle folder?

Comment: does your app work fine ? Bundles are not supposed to be mixed. If you need to add features, you have to extend them.

Comment: Yes, but for example an entity insideApplication/Sonata/userbundle needs an entiy that is inside appBundle/enity. How to solve this?

Comment: Your original entity for exemple MyUser must extend Your sonata user entity.. At least thats how it works with fosuserbundle -- it means that you can add properties to the user, even if it has the ones from sonata

Answer (score 1):

The SonataEasyExtendsBundle creates per default entities inside Application/* folder.

There is no limitation in sonata about class location, so you can move class and adjust the configuration to match the AppBundle convention.

The sonata sandbox now use the AppBundle convention, see https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/tree/2.4-develop/src/AppBundle/Entity